# Email with hyperlink not sent to private email addresses

Tags: php, html-email

I am using following function to send email

```
mail($this->emailTo, $this->subject, $this->body, $this->headers);
```

where, header is set in this way,

```
$this->headers = "From: " . $this->sender . "\r\n"; //from address
        $this->headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $this->headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
```

`$this->emailTo, $this->subject, $this->body, $this->sender` are also set properly.

I have faced a strange problem.

Email body content is html type. It contains hyperlinks too.

Email with any type of content is sent if receiver is gmail/yahoo etc. account type eg. abc@gmail.com, blabla@yahoo.com

Email body  without hyperlink is set to corporate email address eg. dipendra@bajratechnologies.com
But email body with hyperlink is not sent to corporate email address eg. dipendra@bajratechnologies.com

How can this problem is solved? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe your company's spam filter is to blame?

Comment: Check your mail log You will probably find it is sent but your company mail server stops it, it possibly even bounces it but that would show in your mail log

Comment: You should just check your $this->body. Maybe you have "stripped tags".

Comment: same content of $this->body is sent if email address is *@gmail.com but not for corporate email address eg. *@mac.com.

Comment: @Anigel Thank you. Where can I see those logs. It is google apps

Comment: @Dipendra If the email is being rejected by you company email server bajratechnologies.com. You will have to contact YOUR email administrator to view the logs.